# Calculating limits with Strange Rearrangement

Tags: calculus, limits

How did they get to this third step?

$\lim\limits_{x \to 3} \frac{\sqrt{x+1}-2}{\sqrt{x-2}-1}$ =
$\lim\limits_{x \to 3} \frac{(\sqrt{x+1}-2)(\sqrt{x-2}+1)}{x-3}$ =
$\lim\limits_{x \to 3} \frac{(x-3)(\sqrt{x+1}-2)}{(x-3)(\sqrt{x+1}-2)}$

Comment: It's not right.

Comment: I double checked, but perhaps I'm missing something. Here's the original: http://tinypic.com/r/293tzs3/8

Comment: It looks like the third step was either miscopied or changed since you saw it last.  It should be $\sqrt{x-2}+1$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-2}{\sqrt{x-2}-1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x+1}+2}{\sqrt{x-2}+1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x-2}+1}{\sqrt{x+1}+2} \\ \text{ multiply the first two fractions } \\ \text{ Also I multiplied the initial fraction you have by one } $

Comment: After staring at this for a bit, I realized that you were multiplying by the complex conjugate of both fractions. I did get the answer as seen in the above image.